# Rete Tree view not being displayed using drools plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools

I have been trying to display the Rete Tree view for drools files using the drools plugin for eclipse. But it is failing for me with the following error :

I am using Eclipse Indigos, Drools 5.3 and JDK 1.7 .

I googled around a bit to solve this issue but none of the suggestions worked. Any help would be highly appreciated ?

On a parallel note is their any other way to validate the drools rules other than generating the Rete Tree view ? I want to find any syntactical mistakes as early as possible rather than invoking the validations and finding the drl mistakes at runtime.

```
org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:277)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:262)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:175)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:153)
at org.drools.eclipse.DroolsEclipsePlugin.generateParsedResource(DroolsEclipsePlugin.java:393)
at org.drools.eclipse.DroolsEclipsePlugin.generateParsedResource(DroolsEclipsePlugin.java:360)
at org.drools.eclipse.DroolsEclipsePlugin.parseResource(DroolsEclipsePlugin.java:273)
at org.drools.eclipse.editors.DroolsLineBreakpointAdapter.canToggleLineBreakpoints(DroolsLineBreakpointAdapter.java:44)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointAction.update(ToggleBreakpointAction.java:187)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractRulerActionDelegate.update(AbstractRulerActionDelegate.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractRulerActionDelegate.setActiveEditor(AbstractRulerActionDelegate.java:89)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.RulerToggleBreakpointActionDelegate.setActiveEditor(RulerToggleBreakpointActionDelegate.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPluginAction.editorChanged(EditorPluginAction.java:75)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBuilder$EditorContribution.editorChanged(EditorActionBuilder.java:83)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBuilder$ExternalContributor.setActiveEditor(EditorActionBuilder.java:129)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBars.partChanged(EditorActionBars.java:346)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$3.run(WorkbenchPage.java:709)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.activatePart(WorkbenchPage.java:698)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3632)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.requestActivation(WorkbenchPage.java:3159)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.requestActivation(EditorPane.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setFocus(PartPane.java:325)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.setFocus(EditorPane.java:127)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(PartStack.java:837)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(PartStack.java:823)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(PartStack.java:137)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:133)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:278)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$2.handleEvent(DefaultTabFolder.java:88)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I suggest that you report it in the Drools Jira https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES and provide a small example that allows the developers to reproduce it. 

I tested with the setup you have and didn't get the same error. It is possible that your rules have something that breaks the RETE view and I am missing it.